# View Menu with submenu

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on an EclipsePluginProject. I don't have much(nearly nothing) experience with UIs under java. I added a View Option Menu and some actions following [this post](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_actions_to_a_view's_menu_and_toolbar%3F).

```
IMenuManager dropDownMenu = getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager();
dropDownMenu.add(new Action("Action1") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }});
dropDownMenu.add(new Action("Action2") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }});
```

This works great and gives me the following menu:

```
-Action1
-Action2
```

How do i build a submenu which looks like this?

```
-Action > -1
          -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add menus to other menus:

```
IMenuManager rootMenu = getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager();
MenuManager menu = new MenuManager("Menu &2", "2");
menu.add(new Action("Action1") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }});
menu.add(new Action("Action2") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }});
rootMenu.add(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new MenuManager...

```
IMenuManager dropDownMenu = new MenuManager( "Some text", "id" );
```

... add it to your menu ...

```
menuManager.appendToGroup( "yourSection", dropDownMenu );
```

... and add your actions to your new subMenu:

```
dropDownMenu.add(new Action("Action1") {
@Override
public void run() {
    //do something
}});
dropDownMenu.add(new Action("Action2") {
@Override
public void run() {
    //do something
}});
```